# VSFTPD hangs when running a command on RHEL6

Tags: ftp

I'm working to set up a vsftpd server for the first time. This is an openstack VM, so our security and cloud teams have a bunch of default configs that are applied automatically to the vsftpd instance.

Here are our configs (dictated by our security team):

```
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
pasv_enable=NO
```

I created a local system user for ftp called ftpuser. My intention is for users to log in with that user, and write files to that user's directory.

When we try to log in, executing any command whatsoever gives the following:

```
msarro:~/ $ ftp x.x.x.x                                                                                                                      
Connected to x.x.x.x.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (x.x.x.x:msarro): ftpuser
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
550 Permission denied.
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
```

At this point, it hangs.

After about 30 seconds, this message is shown:

```
421 Service not available, remote server timed out. Connection closed.
```

And the connection closes.

We are running vsftpd-2.2.2-13 on RHEL6. I've made sure to add the following line to /etc/hosts.allow:

```
vsftpd : ALL
```

At this point, I can't find any suggestions about how to resolve the issue beyond switching to passive mode. Doing so presents the following:

```
msarro:~/ $ ftp x.x.x.x                                                                                                                      [13:13:08]
Connected to x.x.x.x.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (x.x.x.x:msarro): ftpuser
331 Please specify the password.
Password: 
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||31582|).
```

It then hangs for about 1 minute, and presents the following line:

```
ftp: Can't connect to `x.x.x.x': Operation timed out
200 EPRT command successful. Consider using EPSV.
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At second glance, you have `pasv_enable=NO` making for active FTP, which is a bad idea in most cases.

Comment: I have tried it with both passive and active configured, I edited the post to reflect the different-yet-similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

FTP is always problematic with firewalls because it uses a separate connection for the data.

With active FTP the data connection is back to the client, so it may get blocked by the client firewall (or possibly zealous outgoing rules at the server end).

With passive FTP a second connection is made to the server, which may get blocked by server side firewall. In any case "pasv_enable=NO" rules this out as an option. So you are stuck with active FTP.

So start at server, see if firewall rules are blocking TCP outbound from port 20; then move to border firewall if applicable, then your desktop machine.

Comment: We have both policies and reflexive policies in place between the client and server on both ports 20 and 21, so that shouldn't be an issue (I would think)?

Comment: It hangs immediately on trying to open the data channel, which looks suggestive to me. I would want to see if the SYN packet reaches the client.

Comment: Yeah, I am working with the contractor who owns the box to see if they can get a pcap of the FTP session. Then we can see what is/is-not reaching each device.